# Vector splash screen image with a half of screen size on Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a splash screen with a vector image of size 480dp and radial gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <!-- <solid android:color="#FF07862c"/> -->
            <gradient
                android:type="radial"
                android:startColor="#086824"
                android:endColor="#098a2f"
                android:gradientRadius="480dp"
                android:centerX="0.5"
                android:centerY="0.5"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/background0" android:gravity="center"/> -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
        android:width="480dp"
        android:height="480dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

how to make the the image size

```
min(screen_width, screen_height) / 2
```

(in pseudo-code)?

`apptheme.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this several ways by modifying layer properties of `LayerDrawable` as runtime.
For your `drawable.xml` you can modify the layer at index 1 as follows. then you need to set `windowBackground` at runtime.

```
val layerDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.test) as LayerDrawable
    val size = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels.coerceAtMost(resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels) /2
    layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(1,Gravity.CENTER)
    layerDrawable.setLayerHeight(1,size)
    layerDrawable.setLayerWidth(1,size)
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable)
```

Similarly you can modify any layer if you need. first layer will be a `GradientDrawable` if you need to change it get the drawable for `layerDrawable`  and cast it to `GradientDrawable` . then  you can change its properties.