# Using ImageView and match_parent with splash screen on Android

Tags: android

I can't find a way to simply make my vector image 2/3 of the screen size without the madness with defining [dimens.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494130/vector-splash-screen-image-with-a-half-of-screen-size-on-android) and using [Java/Kotlin code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494130/vector-splash-screen-image-with-a-half-of-screen-size-on-android).

Is it really impossible?

My current implementation of my splash screen:

`drawable/splash.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background0"
        android:width="@dimen/logoSize"
        android:height="@dimen/logoSize"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

`values/dimens.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="logoSize">240dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`values/apptheme.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

it looks like this:

[image]

but when I try to replace `drawable/splash.xml` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background0"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

green image does not appear. Is it possible to fix this?

Or probably is there some other way to use something like `match_parent`+`padding` with splash screen image, but make the image square somehow?

**EDIT1** There is

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

but it works with [ImageView](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/662619), see [Scale image keeping its aspect ratio in background drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891065/scale-image-keeping-its-aspect-ratio-in-background-drawable)

**EDIT2**

Tried to add `match_parent` to my vector image:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:viewportWidth="1000"
    android:viewportHeight="1000">
    ...
```

but got build errors:

```
AAPT: error: 'match_parent' is incompatible with attribute height (attr) dimension.
AAPT: error: 'match_parent' is incompatible with attribute width (attr) dimension.
```

Comment: so create vector image with padding and set size as match_parent

Comment: @Style-7 does `match_parent` work with vector image?

Comment: yes it is , just try

Comment: @Style-7 see EDIT2, is that what you mean?

Comment: no. not in vector, in layer list

Comment: @Style-7 do you mean `drawable/splash.xml`? Are you sure it works here?

Comment: I am not sure.  No need use a layer list. Just use vector with several paths. I can help you later.